# Advice on handling images for ecommerce item creation

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm using an AWS serverless architecture to build an ecommerce platform and was wondering if the following is a smart way to handle images:

- Use S3 for image storage.
- When a new product is uploaded (description, images, etc) it will trigger a lambda function to create different sized images using a node library called `sharp` (a thumbnail, medium and large image size).
- These images will be stored in S3 (forget about caching for now if possible) and the URLs will be saved as part of the product's object in a no-sql DB.
- Do the same for each product image I want to add (i.e. store 3 instances of the same image for each image).

Aside from using a service like cloudinary is this a cheap and scalable way to handle images?

Many thanks

Comment: yes, it seems good to me

Comment: Any advice on how best the file structure should look? Perhaps a folder per product? Is it advisable to include dates in the titles?

`product-images/item-a/item-a-large.jpg` ||
`product-images/item-a/item-a-small.jpg` ||
`product-images/item-a/item-a-thumb.jpg` @jellycsc